# Create Stripe source from token issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, token, stripe-payments

I have a Javascript file of which I am trying to use, to create a Stripe source from a Stripe token. To then be able to submit that source to my form, submit the form and then create a charge from the .php file of which the form submits to.

I am just having some difficulty doing this, I am not getting any errors in my console and it creates the token and source as supposed. However the data is never submitted to my form, as the page never redirects and no charge is ever made.

I am unsure of what exactly I am missing to make it work properly.

Below is an attached image of the console output.

[image]

The code I have so far is the one seen below.

```
    Stripe.card.createToken({
            number: document.getElementById('cardNumId').value,
            cvc: document.getElementById('cvcID').value,
            exp_month: document.getElementById('expMonthId').value,
            exp_year: document.getElementById('expYearId').value
    }, stripeResponseHandler);

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {

    if (response.error) {

        alert('Something went wrong, sorry!' + error);

    } else {

    var token = response.id;

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    stripe.createSource(source, token).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error
      alert('Something went wrong, sorry!' + error);
    } else {
      // Send the source to your server
      stripeSourceHandler(result.source);

    }
  });
  });

    function stripeSourceHandler(source) {

        // Insert the source ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeSource');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', source.id);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

        // Submit the form
        form.submit();

            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this in the Stripe docs:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart